# Rails hidden field sessions possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, session, cookies

Is it possible to pass a session via a hidden form field? (ie POST)

if so if it possible to between the standard method and field sessions on a per controller bases without losing information?

Comment: i can't get your question. Can you tell us clearly?

Comment: Yes instead of cookie based sessions can I use a hidden form field so session id is sent via a HTTP POST request? I know you can pass session id via URLs with rails I wondered if there was a method for HTTP POST so it didn't have to be in the URL and could be in a field instead.

Comment: What do you mean pass a session? Rails has a session variable that you can use in the controller, session[:anything] = "foo" would then return "foo" for session[:anything] in any requests that follow. I don't see why you would want to send the session via a form/POST.

Comment: Arcath because I cant use session cookies (they dont get through because of cross site policies) and I don't want to use URLs because there too open.

Comment: also many old phones have browsers which dont support cookies well

Answer (score 1):

If cookies are disabled, [CGI:Sessions](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/classes/CGI/Session.html) will automatically switch to using hidden fields, however, I'm not certain exactly how this behavior is supported in Rails. Moreover, changing this behavior to require the use of hidden fields may require modifying CGI:Session.

> If the client has cookies disabled, the session id must be included as a parameter of all requests sent by the client to the server. The CGI::Session class in conjunction with the CGI class will transparently add the session id as a hidden input field to all forms generated using the CGI#form() HTML generation method. No built-in support is provided for other mechanisms, such as URL re-writing. The caller is responsible for extracting the session id from the session_id attribute and manually encoding it in URLs and adding it as a hidden input to HTML forms created by other mechanisms. Also, session expiry is not automatically handled.

Therefore, it should be possible to use this method, but as far as I know, it's not supported as a simple option in Rails.

To be clear, even ActiveRecord Session Store uses cookies, so don't equate session stores with how session data is handled by the client.

Finally, at one time there were plugins to support this behavior, but these plugins are old, don't appear to support Rails 3. See the "Non-cookie session" section of [Sessions & Cookies in Ruby on Rails](http://www.quarkruby.com/2007/10/21/sessions-and-cookies-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Yes i know about the old session hidden form gem I cant seem to find the code I was hoping to see how it worked and see if I could hack it.

Comment: I think i'll look at token based authentication